# orphaned users after restore to new machine not on domain; understanding KB918992

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-restore, sid, orphaned-objects

Seeking clarification/confirmation: if I understand correctly, the following considerations about "orphaned users" apply only to those users that are associated with a Windows network security principal; a user associated with a "pure" SQL Server login would not be orphaned when the database is restored to another machine not on the original network and the sp_help_rev_login script is run. Is that right?

from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992 :

> If server A and server B are in different domains, you have to change the output script. Then, you have to replace the original domain name by using the new domain name in the CREATE LOGIN statements. The integrated logins that are granted access in the new domain do not have the same SID as the logins in the original domain. Therefore, users are orphaned from these logins. For more information about how to resolve these orphaned users, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>   240872 How to resolve permission issues when you move a database between servers that are running SQL Server
>   If server A and server B are in the same domain, the same SID is used. Therefore, users are unlikely to be orphaned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you will have the same problem with SQL logins too.  When you restore the database to a new server, only the users in that database will be restored, if logins with matching SIDs are not present on the new server, those users in the database, whether windows or SQL users will be orphaned.